# Can't select wifi CA on Ubuntu 12.10 (Gnome3)

Tags: gnome, wireless, 12.10, certificates

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu 12.10 on a Packard Bell notebook, with Gnome3 instead of Unity.
Now when I try to connect to a WPA/WPA2 Enterprise secured WLAN (PEAP Authentication, MSCHAPv2 as Inner Authentication), after entering the login details I'm prompted to either select a root CA or ignore the message.
But I can't hit the buttons or tick the box to not ask again this question. It's completely unselectable, so I end up not being able to connect to the wifi.
I also tried to select the CA before trying to connect, but what happens then is that the prompt appears while the system starts connecting to the wifi. Unfortunately, it fails to do so.

If you know a way to connect to a wifi with such configuration, I'm also happy with that. The used CA would be the Entrust.net Secure Server Certificate Authority.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had the same issue. I was able to resolve it by logging out, switching to Unity, and connecting to the network there. I think it had something to do with Gnome 3 desktop not being as integrated. I think it only lets you manage one "pop up menu" at a time. In Unity, it doesn't open the Network Settings in the background, so you can click Ignore or you can choose a CA.

If you don't have Unity even installed, I suppose you could also try to do it from the command line using the following:

1. Create a wpa_supplicant.conf file. [This](http://www.nowiressecurity.com/articles/configure_8021x_authentication_in_linux.htm) seems to be a relatively good guide for how to create your configuration file, and I am drawing from it for the rest of the instructions. Your configuration file should look something like this:

   ```
   network = {

   ssid="Your_ssid_here"
   key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
   pairwise=TKIP
   group=TKIP
   eap=PEAP
   identity="user@your_domain"
   password="your_password"
   ca_cert="/path/to/cert"
   phase1="peapver=0"
   phase2="MSCHAPV2"
   }
   ```
2. Then, you must start issue the following command:

   ```
   wpa_supplicant -B -c/path/to/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0
   ```

   The "-B" flag makes the daemon run in the background. The "-c" followed by the path     loads the config file you created earlier, and the "-iwlan0" should be replaced with your wireless interface.
3. If you want to keep this after a reboot, add the following to your /etc/network/interfaces file.

   ```
   auto wlan0
   iface wlan0 inet dhcp
   pre-up wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
   post-down killall -q wpa_supplicant
   ```

Hope this helps! If you have questions, you can always check the man page for wpa_supplicant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Setting the wifi up through Unity worked perfectly fine, I stored the connection and hope that it will work after reboot. However, setting up the wpa_supplicant using the conf-file did not work. First thing is, it has to be network={ (without the spaces), apparently. Second thing is, even when doing so I get the error "ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument" when I enter the command you wrote down...

Comment: So just configuring the connection through Unity desktop solves the problem? Still, this seems like a major regression from Gnome Shell 3.4... Isn't there a way to set the number of maximum pop-up windows through a G-conf key?

Comment: Yes, it indeed solves the problem, and after you have the connection stored, it will stay, so after a reboot you can just log in to Gnome Shell right away, as it apparently uses the same connection configuration. 
I think it's a bug in Gnome Shell... But maybe that's something one could try.